# how to fetch and assign a list of strings which are values of map

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

Below mentioned is map, where I stored list of string based on string key.

```
 std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>>mapheaderToFields;
    list<string> strlist;
```

Now I would like return list, and I would like to assign that return list to Newly created list variable. How can I do that?

I tried to achieve that using below mentioned code snippet. But,I couldn't be able to assign it to a list.
Any suggestions on how to approach on this problem.

```
for (iteHeaderToField = mapheaderToFields.begin(); iteHeaderToField != mapheaderToFields.end(); iteHeaderToField++)
    {
        cout << "key :" << iteHeaderToField->first<<endl;
        strlist.assign((iteHeaderToField->second.begin(),(iteHeaderToField->second.end());
        ((_mapHeaderToFields.find((iteHeaderToField)->first)));
    }
```

I tried to fetch second element from a map and assigned it to list.but, I couldn't be able to assign to list. Compiler is throwing error when I assigned it to a list.

is there any other way which I can make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `std::list`'s [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/operator%3D)

```
strlist = iteHeaderToField->second;
```

This will copy the list pointed by the iterator second element into `strlist`.